# BlueZ D-Bus Media API: Is there any way to set the playback position?

Tags: bluetooth, media-player, dbus, bluez

I'm trying to build a bluetooth-receiver which can control the different media players on my smartphone (Spotify, Apple Music...) using the BlueZ D-Bus Media API:

https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/doc/media-api.txt

Most functions work fine so far (e.g. Play(), Pause(), Next()...). At the moment I'm struggling how to implement the commands from the position bar. When I move the slider in the position bar I want the playback to jump to that position. Unfortunately BlueZ D-Bus Media API does not offer a method like SetPosition() or something like that.

The best solution I found so far is to use the methods FastForward() or Rewind() multiple times which jump through the playback in 10-second-steps. That works fine for short songs but takes way too long (many seconds) for podcasts which are often longer than one hour.The ideal would be a method which can set the position of the playback depending on the slider in the position bar.

My question: Is there any way to set a specific position of the playback?

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth [A/V Remote Control Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/a-v-remote-control-profile-1-6-2/) does not provide for setting a dedicated position within a media file. Therefore, I am afraid that this function is also not available in the BlueZ Media API.

Comment: Thank you for the notice about the AVRCP. Now I understand why the API doesn't support this function. If anyone has a good idea how to implement this functionality with the given functions please let me know.